# I want that in my project the members who are having role as manager should not be able to see the priority field while updating the form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want that in my project the members who are having role as manager should not be able to see the priority field while updating the form

## models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):

    status_choice = (
        ("Approval", "Approval"),
        ("Assigned", "Assigned"),
        ("Scoping", "Scoping"),
        ("In Progress", "In Progress"),
        ("Completed", "Completed"),
        ("Cancelled", "Cancelled"),
        ("Rejected", "Rejected"),
    )
    priority_choice = (
        ("High", "High"),
        ("Moderate", "Moderate"),
        ("Low", "Low"),
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey("vats.Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey("vats.Subcategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(
        _("Title"),
        max_length=50,
    )
    problem_descp = models.TextField(_("Problem Description"), max_length=500)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey("registration.User", related_name=_("Issues"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.CharField(_("Priority"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, choices=priority_choice)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Start Date Time"), auto_now_add=True)
    end_date_time = models.DateTimeField(_("End Date Time"), null=True, blank=True)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey("registration.User", related_name=_("Tasks"), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(_("Status"), max_length=50, choices=status_choice, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Ticket")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tickets")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def is_open(self):
        if self.status == "Completed" or self.status == "Cancelled":
            return False
        return True
```

## forms.py

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # subcategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subcategory.objects.filter(category__id = self.fields['category']))

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ("category", "subcategory", "title", "problem_descp")


class TicketUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ("category", "subcategory", "title", "problem_descp", "status", "assigned_to", "priority")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TicketUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["category"].disabled = True
        self.fields["subcategory"].disabled = True
        self.fields["title"].disabled = True
        self.fields["problem_descp"].disabled = True
```

Comment: Why do you disable all these fields in the `TicketUpdateForm`?

Comment: Depending on how you define "having a role", you can just do e.g. `del self.fields["priority"]` in `__init__()` (if you pass in the request or user to do so).